# Replacing a shared library with a shared microservice

Tags: microservices, libraries, architectural-patterns

I understand that generally shared libraries are a microservice antipattern, and the disadvantages of shared libraries in a microservice world are well documented.

However, I have not been able to find much information on extracting something like core library code into a shared service. What are the advantages and disadvantages of maintaining a common service as opposed to a shared library?

Answer (score 2):

The disadvantage is performance. Rather than call a method that lives in your address space you're hitting a resource at a URL. That takes more time.

The advantage is that everything that needs this method doesn't have n different copies of it from however many different versions on however many systems. The method lives at one URL only. That gives you a single authority.

The real secret to microservices is they found an address space that doesn't just live in one box. It lives in the whole world.

Comment: Specifically the time here is call latency.  If you make a lot these calls it will add up quick.  If this is a infrequent and resource intensive call, being able to scale horizontally might be beneficial.

Comment: `What are the advantages and disadvantages of **maintaining** a common service as opposed to a shared library?` There is a pattern that makes maintaining a lot easier : If you define a java-interface that is implemented by the microservice and by your shared-library (that implements the service) (asssuming you are using java) than the code that consumes the microservice or shared-library will only be programmed against the interface. It is very easy then to replace shared-lib against mircroservice and vice versa. only minor setup changes are neccesary.